# C#: ArgumentException when calling System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll

I am in a bit of a strange situation.  I have been given a fairly large suite of PowerShell modules and functions, and it is my job to tie these together into an executable.  The requirements state that this must be a single, standalone executable with no installer and .net 3.5 may be the only dependency. The Windows Management Framework is not an exception and cannot be assumed to exist on the machine.  To get around this, I have added System.Management.Automation as a reference and made it an embedded resource, along with all of the PowerShell module files, and load them from reflection at runtime.  This seems to work OK, but I have some errors that I cannot seem to figure out and think it might have something to do with this system.

So Here is the issue: When I start to initialize things to run the PowerShell command, I get a strange error that I can't seem to control.

Here is the code:

```
public static void RunCommand(object objcommand)
    {
        //create a script block for toolbox once, get the embeded resource, convert from byte array to string, make scriptblock from string
        ScriptBlock toolbox = System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Properties.Resources.toolbox));
        string command = (string)objcommand;
        //get the module name
        string modname = options.Commands[command]["module"];
        //get the module from the embeded resources, convert to string, convert to scriptblock
        var module = System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(new System.IO.StreamReader(myasm.GetManifestResourceStream("piramids.Resources." + modname + ".psm1")).ReadToEnd());
        using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace rs = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(); //i think this line triggers the exception
            rs.Open();
            powerShell.Runspace = rs;


            //make the necesary powershell modules of the command availible
            powerShell.AddCommand("new-module").AddParameter("ScriptBlock", toolbox).Invoke();
            powerShell.AddCommand("new-module").AddParameter("ScriptBlock", module).Invoke();


            //if inethistory, make dlls availible
            if (modname.Equals("inethistory"))
            {
                powerShell.AddCommand("add-type").AddParameter("Path", sqldll).Invoke();
                powerShell.AddCommand("add-type").AddParameter("Path", esentdll).Invoke();
            }



            ICollection<PSObject> output = new List<PSObject>(0);
            try {
                output = powerShell.AddCommand("get-" + command).AddCommand(format).AddCommand("out-string").Invoke();//pipeline.Invoke();
            } catch (System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException e)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("An Error occured while executing '" + command + "'");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        //do stuff with the results
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
    at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(String fileName)
    at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
    at System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo.GetPSVersionTable()
    at System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo.get_PSVersion()
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.DefaultHost..ctor(CultureInfo currentCulture, CultureInfo currentUICulture)
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    at piramids.Program.RunCommand(Object objcommand)
    at piramids.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I believe this line is where the exception occurs:

```
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace rs = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
```

The CreateRunspace method is not documented to throw any exceptions, and this exception comes from so many levels down that I have no idea what kind of path this thing is checking, as I never called a function that asked for a path.

I am stumped. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this?

EDIT: After some digging, here is what I found.  PSVersionTable is a static field of VersionInfo, so the static constructor is called the first time get called for this field. The static constructor calls an internal method called GetBuildVersion, which tries to get the assembly location of PSVersionInfo.  According to [This documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the assembly is loaded from a byte array, such as when using the Load(Byte[]) method overload, the value returned is an empty string ("").

I am loading from a byte array, so this will be an empty string. But then GetBuildVersion uses this location to do FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo which verifies the path with Path.GetFullPath. According to [This documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ArgumentException:
>   the path is a zero-length string

So there is the problem. Now the question is, How do I assign a location to an assembly loaded from a byte array? May God have mercy on me.

Comment: Which line triggers the exception?

Comment: sorry, this one:
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace rs = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

Comment: Using reflector on GetPSVersionTable() gives: "string location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string fileVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(location).FileVersion;". Are your running your program from a "special" location?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've been running it from the directory that Visual Studio compiles to as well as from my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all convinced this is even remotely reasonable to expect PowerShell code to work without installing WMF. If I were approached with that request I would respond that all code must be rebuilt in another .NET language (that is, C#).

Still, perhaps you can see if it's this static method. You'll have to de-PowerShell the code I'm afraid. The PowerShell accelerator is just a simple way for me to get at the System.Management.Automation assembly. The class is not public and the method on the class is not public either.

$verInfo = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetTypes() | Where-Object Name -eq 'PSVersionInfo'
   $verInfo.GetMethod('get_PSVersion', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic,Static').Invoke($null, [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic,Static', $null, @(), $null)

Chris